# Jboss application startup and shutdown asks for password. How to automate with init script?

Tags: solaris, password, init-script

Jboss application startup and shutdown of BMC-IDM asks for password (called keystore password, some Java stuff).

How to automate with init script?

Stop application

```
> stop_idm_suite.sh
Suite system password:
```

start application

```
> start_idm_suite.sh
-Didm.suite.home=/opt/jboss-app/bmc/idm/idm-suite7.5       -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/jboss-app/bmc/idm/idm-suite7.5/security/keystore/idm.keystore -Dlog4j.configuration=-there-aint-no-such-file- -Djava.awt.headless=true -Didoox.debug.logger=log4j -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=258m -XX:PermSize=128m -Doracle.home=/opt/jboss-app/oracle/product/10.2.0/client_1 -Dess.root=/opt/jboss-app/bmc/idm/idm-suite7.5/ess_api

Suite system password:
```

Tried with 
    start_idm_suite.sh < password-file
but no luck

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Oracle-IDM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10391_01/doc.910/e10370/starting_oim.htm) documentation this should happen only once during startup. Afterwards it should use the encrypted stored password.

**Update** 2012-11-13: I think that BMC-IDM must have a similar mechanism.
Try to start the Application with `strace -e open -f start_idm_suite.sh`. I would expect to see a failed open just before the password gets asked.

That will probably the file where the password needs to be stored to.

**Update** 2014-02-15: Use `truss` on Solaris.

Comment: It true that we only need to give password once at startup. But wish to automate that. We don't use Oracle-IDM, we use BMC "Identity Management Suite" if it does matter.

Comment: @fyodor78 the product matters, indeed. I will update your question with that information. From the path I thought you were using Oracle-IDM... I will update my answer as well.

Comment: it's a Solaris 10 box, so there is no "strace".

Comment: Try alternative, called truss http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Unix/Solaris/SOLARIS_UsingthetrussCommandinSolaris.shtml

Comment: @bbaja42 Right - that was `strace` on solaris. I updated my answer. This was an opensource addon for Solaris afaik.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the script, it's about the keystore.

> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/jboss-app/bmc/idm/idm-suite7.5/security/keystore/idm.keystore

When you define a keystore that's protected by a password, you need to supply this password with the following line:

> -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=KeyStorePass

where KeyStorePass is the password protecting the keystore (by default changeit).

So, edit the script and modify it to add this line. Be careful and protect the script for being read by undesired users.

Check the password of your keystore with:

> keytool -list -keystore /opt/jboss-app/bmc/idm/idm-suite7.5/security/keystore/idm.keystore

It will ask for the keystore password and list the PK in it.

Comment: Check the password of your keystore with:

Comment: Note that adding the password with a command-line option such as `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=KeyStorePass` makes the password visible to anyone and everyone who can log onto the host.